# Prove that for all $n$ $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}=\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1$ , $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}$ is the fractional part

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that for all $n$ $\{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}=\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1$

we know that $\{x\}=x-\left\lfloor {x}\right \rfloor $ and we also know that
$\left\lfloor {x}\right \rfloor=n$ $\iff$ $n \leq x < n+1$

so I believe that we need to get to something similar to that

we know that $n^2-1 \geq 0$ because of the domain  so we can do
$0 \leq n^2-1 < n $ $\Rightarrow$ non negative values so we can square them $\sqrt{n^2-1} < \sqrt{n} = |n| =n$ so we got $\sqrt{n^2-1} < n$ and I could not figure out how to continue it or even if I started right

the book does not show full answers but it has this and I cannot understand why

in the book they got to $n-1 \leq \sqrt{n^2-1} <n$ and then they wrote "according to floor and ceiling properties" $\left\lfloor{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right \rfloor =x-1$ these are supposed to be the last steps and we need to prove before using but the book only shows the final answers

$\left\lfloor{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right \rfloor =x-1$
why does that happen?

and why $n-1 \leq \sqrt{n^2-1} <n$

thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: Why don't you square the inequality on the last line?

Comment: @Nightflight which part?

Comment: The assumption is that $n\ge 1$?

Comment: @Bernard it does not say anything about $n \geq 1$ in the question it just says for every n , but I am assume it is since it is with a square root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\sqrt{n^2-1}<\sqrt{n^2}=n$.
2. If $n\ge 1$, $\enspace n-1 \le\sqrt{n^2-1}\iff(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1\le n^2-1\iff 2(n-1)\ge 0$.

Therefore, we have $\; n-1\le \sqrt{n^2-1} <n$, so that $\;\Bigl\lfloor\sqrt{n^2-1}\Bigr\rfloor=n-1$, and consequently
$$\Bigl\{\sqrt{n^2-1} \Bigr\}=\sqrt{n^2-1} - n+1.$$

Comment: thank you for the help I just struggle to understand the second inequality $n-1 \leq \sqrt{n^2-1}$ where did it come from? sorry for the question again

Comment: @Adamrk: You don't  have to be sorry – it seems I wasn't explicit enough. Actually, I meant this line as a proof of the inequality, since , squaring both sides, it shows it is equivalent to $2(n-1)\ge 0$, which is a direct consequence of the hypothesis on $n$. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

$n-1<n+1$ and $n-1\ge0$, so...

$$
(n-1)^2\le(n-1)(n+1)=n^2-1<n^2
\\
n-1\le\sqrt{n^2-1}<n, [\sqrt{n^2-1}]=n-1, \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}=\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1
$$